# Почему composer выдает ошибку?

Tags: laravel, composer

Поставил `composer` в директорию проекта по инструкции со страницы [Composer Download](https://getcomposer.org/download/). 
Следом, в папке проекта делаю:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

И выдает :

```
-bash: composer: command not found
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по вашей ссылке composer устанавливается локально.
в этом случаи используйте `php composer.phar`.
т.е `php composer.phar global require "laravel/installer"`

чтобы поставить composer глобально:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: Есть, работает, спасибо)